# Restangular get response errors

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a simple auth factory in angular with the following codes

```
.factory 'User',($window,$rootScope,Restangular)->
    {
        auth: (username,password)->
            Restangular.all 'auth/login/'
            .post {username:username,password:password}
            .then (response)->
                return response
            ,(response) ->
                return response
        .....
```

and i am calling that from my controller using

```
$scope.login = ()->
    $scope.running = 1
    console.log User.auth $scope.username,$scope.password
    $scope.running = 0
    return
```

The problem is that i need to show the errors on login if any and set them in `controller` but `restangular` being async, i am not sure how to do to same. As you can see from the first code segment that i tried to return the values but even they don't seem to work.

How can i get the reponse codes from the server in **scope** using **Restangular**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the restangular call, which is a promise. Then on the callbacks you can do something with the errors:

```
auth: (username,password)->
    return Restangular.all 'auth/login/'
    .post {username:username,password:password}
```

controller:

```
$scope.login = ()->
    $scope.running = 1
    User.auth( $scope.username,$scope.password)
    .then (response)->
        // success
    ,(response)->
        // fail
    .finally (response)->
        $scope.running = 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was looking for something to avoid this. Anyway the code works now :)